# Modify UISearchBar width in a UITableView header

Tags: ios, width, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm running the following snippet of code (in ViewDidLoad method of a UITableViewController) to create a UISearchBar and add it to a UITableView header.

```
UISearchBar search = new UISearchBar();
search.SizeToFit (); // How to modify width?
TableView.TableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Do you if there is a workaround to modify the width of the UISearchBar. The previous snippet of code allows the bar to have a width as the screen one. Giving a frame to the bar seems not working.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** The sample has been created for MonoTouch, but it can apply for iOS in general.

Comment: I have very similar issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571676/uisearchbar-in-uitableview-header-layout-issue-in-ios-14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I found:

- create a UIToolbar
- add the UISearchBar to that toolbar
- add the toolbar to the header of a UITableView

Since in a UIToolbar it is possible to insert space elements (i.e. UIBarButtonItemFlexibleSpace), the width of a search bar can be modified easily.

Comment: Why relay on UIToolbar's messy layout system, when a simple UIView should be sufficient?

Comment: Because I need the same color layout as that of UIToolbar. In addiction, I need to resize the width of my search bar. Do you have any other advice? Thanks

Comment: you can cut a 1x44 image slice of the toolbar from the simulator and use a uiview and set backgroundcolor to to uicolorwithpatterenedimage: