# UISearchBar in UITableView header layout issue in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using the new UISearchController with searchbar inside tableview header.Everything works fine in portrait orientation but when I rotate to landscape and uisearchbar start editing its frame is out of screen,clipping the cancel button.
my code for creating searchcontroller

`tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`

Here is my sample code [UISearchController sample](https://github.com/Waseemasif05/UISearchControllerTutorial)

Rotation has no frame issue in landscape but only when uisearchbar starts editing [[image: landscape searchbar]

[image: Cancel button clipping]

When rotate back to portrait layout of uisearchbar is still incorrect[image: portrait screen after rotating back]
There is no issue if I use UITableviewController but I have to implement with uitableview.Is there any setting I am missing in iOS 14 ?

Note:I have to use tableHeaderView not `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

Comment: May or may not be a solution for you, but... try constraining the tableView Leading and Trailing to `superView` instead of `safe-area`.

Comment: I don't know why you "have to implement with UITableView"? Just use the tools available to you. Why make life difficult for yourself?

Comment: @Abizern uitableview give me more flexibility to add more views to my screen in future.these are old issues that things supporting easily on uitableviewcontroller not working with uitableview

Comment: @Waseem05 you can use view controller containment and let the table view controller control the tableview, and you can still add other views (or view controllers) to your main vc.

Answer (score -1):

Try adjusting the frame of search bar in `viewWillTransition` method that in your  corresponding `UIViewController` . `viewWillTransition` is called every time during rotation and enables you to change layout during rotation of your `UIViewController`.

here is example code:

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate( alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
        adjustSearchbarFrame()
    }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
    })
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```